# C# Local Directory referencing in Exception Message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

I have released an executable file for my company in C# using Visual Studio 2010. But the thing is , everytime it throws out an exception, it keeps referencing back to my local directory in which code line number it was caught on. Not the current environment that it's in.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: There is already a tab with the same name. Rename it please
   at CSVToXLSX.ApplicationArguments..ctor(String[] args) in C:\Users\zhangh9\Do
      cuments\Projects\CSVToXLSX\CSVToXLSX\ApplicationArguments.cs:line 133
   at CSVToXLSX.Program.XlsxCreator(String[] args) in C:\Users\zhangh9\Documents
      \Projects\CSVToXLSX\CSVToXLSX\Program.cs:line 16
   at CSVToXLSX.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\zhangh9\Documents\Projec
       ts\CSVToXLSX\CSVToXLSX\Program.cs:line 11
```

Is there anyway I can remove that whole section, or customize/configure it the way that I want it to be?

Comment: Maybe you could... idk... handle the exception? :)

Comment: Don't hand out debug builds and/or builds that include PDB files?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever are you saying release builds with the symbols will reference the project location? I didn't know that

Comment: How do you build without PDB files?

Answer (score 0):

This will be the location the executable was built in, you can change it only by changing that location and move it to somewhere else when building.

A better solution would be to deal with the exception and not have it bubble up to the user in such a manner.